# Duplicate the view of a component in javafx

Tags: javafx

I am looking for a way to duplicate just the view of a component in javafx. This duplicate will not have any of the mouse or key events, and will basically be like a canvas.
As long as this duplicate doesn't change, I can use the snapshot(...) method that nodes have. My problem is that I want this to be dynamic. For example, I have one pane which displays some sort of animation (which can depend on user input), and I want a second pane which show the exact same image (but cannot have in itself user input like mouse presses).
The reflection effect is very specific case of what I need. Is there any way to do it in general?

One way to do it (which I used so far) is to just create a second duplicate component and connect all its input to the first. The problem is that this is a lot of work for every component that I want to copy, and it cannot be done generically.
A second way is just to take a snapshot every time the original component changes and copy it to the duplicate. This should be the solution, but I think that there is supposed to be a more low level solution instead of listening to changes, create an Image duplicate and then update an ImageView.

Comment: Post some working code of your attempt.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Sedrick I don't really have any example, and I also explained what are the possible solutions. Your answer below is one of these possibilities which I wanted to avoid, because it works specifically just for a circle and just for its center. If you now want to do it for a square, you need to rewrite everything. If you want to do it to a pane which contains a lot of other components, then without knowing exactly what are these components you cannot even do the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of binding. This is a basic example

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Separator;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXTestingGround extends Application
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    Circle circle = new Circle(0, 200, 25, Color.BLUE);
    Circle duplicateCircle = new Circle(25, Color.BLUE);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        duplicateCircle.centerXProperty().bind(circle.centerXProperty());
        duplicateCircle.centerYProperty().bind(circle.centerYProperty());

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.0 / 40.0), (ActionEvent t) -> {
            circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() + 1);
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        circle.setOnMouseClicked((t) -> {
            switch (timeline.getStatus()) {
                case STOPPED:
                    timeline.play();
                    break;
                case RUNNING:
                    timeline.stop();
                    break;
            }
        });

        Pane root = new Pane(circle);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();

        Pane duplicateRoot = new Pane(duplicateCircle);
        Stage duplicatStage = new Stage();
        duplicatStage.setScene(new Scene(duplicateRoot, 400, 400));
        duplicatStage.setX(primaryStage.getX() + primaryStage.getWidth() + 10);
        duplicatStage.setY(primaryStage.getY());
        duplicatStage.show();
    }
}
```